# mysql return domain from string

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I have this long string below and my task is to return findwhitepapers.com. Basically, I need domain from this email, but this email is in the long string with different characters.

```
<p><t1>soverflow@findwhitepapers.com</t1><t2>test</t2><t3>test</t3><t4>test</t4><t5></t5><t6>test</t6><t7>t4h1a6</t7><t8>test</t8><t9>2345554444</t9><t11>test</t11><t12></t12><s1>2</s1><s2>9</s2><s4>58</s4><s7>130</s7><s1108></s1108><s993>4444</s993></p>

select person_snapshot, 
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTR(person_snapshot, 
    INSTR(person_snapshot, '@') + 1),'.',1)) 
FROM lead_event LIMIT 100;
```

I have tried this, but it only returns findwhitepapers. Can I get the domain from the string above?

Comment: So how do you define where the domain ends without giving it a list of possible tlds? Or you have only .coms?

Comment: sorry edit has been made.

Comment: You are nearly there: Once you have found the @whitepapers part (which you did), then you have to use that to search for the parts after that in the same style (so more instr substring code but then using the previous result)

Comment: Instead of using `.` as delimiter use `<` in SUBSTRING_INDEX.